# Booltool addon not punch a hole

Tags: modifiers, add-on

With the inbuilt booltool addon. Why i can't punch a hole. The face facing correct. Removed double verts, scale rotation are 1 and 0,. Mesh has subsurf, solidify, mirror modifier. Im using 2.9 version after boolean with brush cant find the properties canvas to remove the brush. What missing or where im  going wrong. Any suggestion.

[image]

[image]

[Gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiNn0.jpg)

Comment: The edge split modifier of the cutter object makes it non manifold. Try to remove it.

Comment: @lemon Thanks. where properties canvas menu disappear in 2.9. as shown in question

Comment: I used today 2.91 and after brush Difference "Canvas" part appered ... so I cant confirm your screen. (I used your blend as it is. Even with Edge Split modifier.)

Answer (score 0):

### Bool Tool fail

In provided file the *Bool Tool*, brush type *Difference*, works for me.

But your screen of "helmet" object looks differently. On screen *Mirror* modifier has unchecked **Merge**, so if you used it in this condition - Bool Tool failed.

[image]

### Missing Canvas menu

This menu appears only when a brush is used. Than you can see properties menu when "Canvas" object is selected. BTW you have selected "Brush" object. So when boolean operation is used also here "Brush" properties appears when selected.

[image]

Comment: Does it answered your Q?